# Loading another scene in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

In kinect 1.7 wrapper package for unity, when switching between scenes i'm getting an error  " There can be only one instance of  kinectsensor. " can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: check your Game Objects and their components. I am not familiar with this package but it sounds like two objects have the same component which can only *once be active* or *exist in only one place*. It sounds similar to the listeners on the camera objects. Make sure only one exists in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Script from this

```
if (KinectSensor.instance != null)
   {
      Debug.Log("There should be only one active instance of the KinectSensor component at at time.");
      throw new Exception("There should be only one active instance of the KinectSensor component at a time.");
   }
```

to

```
if (KinectSensor.instance != null)
{
   Debug.Log("There should be only one active instance of the KinectSensor component at at time.");
KinectSensor.instance = null; // Add this one
}
```

If this not worked, might be delet your camera of your 1st scene while shifting to second scene.